# Is there method startswith in xojo like in Java or Vb.Net?

Tags: textfield, startswith, xojo

I try to learn xojo. Is there any method Startswith in xojo just like in Java and Vb.net? If there is, how should I implement it?
Thank you.

Comment: http://docs.xojo.com/index.php/Category:Language_Reference

Answer (score 1):

In the old framework there is no equivalent so you will have to code it yourself using Left.

Strings in Xojo are, by default, case insensitive and this would work:

```
Function BeginsWith(extends aString as string, startString as String) As Boolean  
  Return ( Left( aString, len( startString))=startString )
End Function
```

If you want case sensitivity you could so this:

```
Function BeginsWithNoCase(extends aString as string, startString as String) As Boolean
  dim s1,s2 as string
  s1 = Uppercase( aString)
  s2 = Uppercase( startString)
  Return ( Left( s1, len( s2))=s2 )
End Function
```

This and more at https://forum.xojo.com/19302-is-there-method-startswith-in-xojo/0#p162011

Answer (score 1):

Use [Text.BeginsWith](http://developer.xojo.com/text$BeginsWith). It supports both case-insensitive and case-sensitive comparisons.